# ApnsPHP - Getting error while sending Push Notification

Tags: php, ios, apple-push-notifications, apns-php

I integrated Push Notification library for sending out Push Notifications. When i tested it on my local machine it worked fine but when i uploaded library sample code to live server it throws me error, I pasted the response below...What i found the real error in this whole response is --> 'ERROR: Unable to send message ID 1: Missing payload (4)'.  I need help to resolve this issue.

```
Thu, 18 Apr 2013 12:58:29 +0200 ApnsPHP[17833]: INFO: Trying ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195... 
Thu, 18 Apr 2013 12:58:30 +0200 ApnsPHP[17833]: INFO: Connected to ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195.
Thu, 18 Apr 2013 12:58:30 +0200 ApnsPHP[17833]: INFO: Sending messages queue, run #1: 1 message(s) left in queue. 
Thu, 18 Apr 2013 12:58:30 +0200 ApnsPHP[17833]: STATUS: Sending message ID 1 [custom identifier: Message-Badge-33] (1/3): 45 bytes. 
Thu, 18 Apr 2013 12:58:30 +0200 ApnsPHP[17833]: ERROR: Unable to send message ID 1: Missing payload (4). 
Thu, 18 Apr 2013 12:58:30 +0200 ApnsPHP[17833]: INFO: Disconnected. Thu, 18 Apr 2013 12:58:30 +0200 ApnsPHP[17833]: INFO: Trying ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195... 
Thu, 18 Apr 2013 12:58:30 +0200 ApnsPHP[17833]: INFO: Connected to ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195. 
Thu, 18 Apr 2013 12:58:30 +0200 ApnsPHP[17833]: INFO: Sending messages queue, run #2: 1 message(s) left in queue. 
Thu, 18 Apr 2013 12:58:30 +0200 ApnsPHP[17833]: WARNING: Message ID 1 [custom identifier: Message-Badge-33] has an unrecoverable error (4), removing from queue without retrying... 
Thu, 18 Apr 2013 12:58:31 +0200 ApnsPHP[17833]: INFO: Disconnected.
```

.

```
array(1) { [1]=> array(3) 
{ 
   ["MESSAGE"]=> object(ApnsPHP_Message)#3 (9) 
   { 
    ["_bAutoAdjustLongPayload:protected"]=> bool(true) ["_aDeviceTokens:protected"]=> array(1)
    { 
      [0]=> string(64) "FB7B2A31F06532EAD2973C1512A27A4F48FE22D9AFB9EE9F33B566B73A768935" 
    } 
   ["_sText:protected"]=> string(26) "Hello APNs-enabled device!" ["_nBadge:protected"]=> int(3) ["_sSound:protected"]=> string(7) "default" ["_bContentAvailable:protected"]=> NULL ["_aCustomProperties:protected"]=> array(2) 
  { 
    ["acme2"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "bang" [1]=> string(4) "whiz" } 
    ["acme3"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "bing" [1]=> string(4) "bong" } 
  }
  ["_nExpiryValue:protected"]=> int(30) ["_mCustomIdentifier:protected"]=> string(16) "Message-Badge-33" 
   } 
  ["BINARY_NOTIFICATION"]=> string(45) "QoÑô û{*1ðe2êÒ—<¢zOHþ"Ù¯¹îŸ3µf·:v‰5" ["ERRORS"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(5) { ["command"]=> int(8) ["statusCode"]=> int(4) ["identifier"]=> int(1) ["time"]=> int(1366282710) ["statusMessage"]=> string(15) "Missing payload" 
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Thanks in advance

PS: Someone in google groups also posted the same issue but the solution is not available.

Comment: Thanks @Deanna for fixing the formatting...@Dave do u know anything about this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a day of tests, I've located the problem: the json_encode function takes 2nd parameter "options" from 5.3 PHP version:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Locally i have PHP V5.3.x, so the code worked fine with 2nd parameter in json_encode function. But on live server PHP version is 5.2.6, so 2nd parameter in code for json_encode causing issue and throwing "Missing Payload" error. I just removed 2nd parameter and it works fine for me :)

Comment: Luckily I came across your answer to this within ten minutes of investigating the same error. Thanks for answering your question! Exactly the same problem for me.

Comment: Note that apns-php explicitly requires php >= 5.3, in fact.